# Class reference member - Not an error in a class with synthesized constructor but error in user defined constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Below errors out. Understood.

```
class a {
   int b;
   int &c; // uninitialized
   a(int x): b(x) {}
};
```

Below uses synthesized constructor. Why no error below? How does the synthesized constructor initialize the reference or will it even do that? Reference has to be user initialized from what I understand.

```
class a {
   int b;
   int &c;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error in your first class comes here:

```
a(int x): b(x) {}  // error
```

This is because you've defined a constructor that doesn't initialize the reference member `c`. This is an ill-formed constructor, and so the compiler gives an error.

In the second class, the compiler will synthesize a constructor, so there's no error. However, that constructor is defined as deleted, and so you won't be able to create an object of this type.

```
a test1{};      // error
a test2{1, n};  // also error (assuming n is an int)
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sqv3nqx44)

---

So essentially, the error in the first case is that the class definition is ill-formed. In the second case, it's a well-formed class with a deleted constructor, which may be intentional.

Comment: cigien types faster than me. Here's the bones of what I was working on that demonstrates where the "working" class falls over and dies a hard death.https://godbolt.org/z/7G51nhzYe

Comment: working class. Huh. now we have blue collar objects?

Comment: @user4581301 oops, I didn't mean to ninja anyone :) The demo is a good idea, mind if I steal it?

Comment: Hardly ninja-ing. I know I'm slow, and your description of the problem was better than mine. It's part of the of the Stack Overflow "game". Feel free to use the example.

Comment: @yapkm01 No, not at all. Different users have different motives for asking/answering/curating etc, but money is not one of them, since no one gets paid for doing any of it. I'm actually curious why you're asking; with your rep you must know by now that there's no money involved.

Comment: Oh I am not really a stackoverflow expert user and I hardly know what those rep etc are.  I don't take notice of them if I have bad or good reputation.  Reason I ask is just out of curiosity.  Because everytime I post it seems users are rushing to answer. So just thought could be due to $$$. Just curious. Now I know that's not true.  Tx.